# How to read MySQL table into shiny app fast

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, data.table

My Shiny app currently reads from a table in MySQL with

```
cn <- dbConnect(drv      = RMySQL::MySQL(), 
                username = "my_username", 
                password = "my_password", 
                host     = "host_address", 
                port     = 3306,
                dbname   = 'schema_name'
                )

df <- dbReadTable(cn, 'table_name')#reads as a data.frame

ui<- dashboardPage(...)

server<- function(input, output, session){...}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

However, table is 5 million rows long with about 10 columns, so every time I start up the app, it takes a few minutes to load.

I know a lot of people suggest using a `data.table` instead of `data.frame` by using `fread`, but `fread` doesn't seem to work with `dbConnect` - most examples I've seen involve `fread` reading a csv file locally stored, and I don't want to export that SQL table locally since it changes every now and then.

There also seems to be another way where after I finish waiting for `df <- dbReadTable(cn, 'table_name')#reads as a data.frame`, I can call `as.data.table(df)` to transform it into a `datatable`. While this might improve future operation speeds over `dplyr`, I'm still stuck waiting for `dbReadTable` to load when I first open the app.

I've also already pre-processed the data, so to speak, so I don't think I can further reduce the size of the table.

Any suggestions / best practice advice here to quickly load the data from SQL?

Comment: Maybe you can load the data only when needed, and applying filter and select according to your needs (5M*10 = 50M information is probably a little too much for your user to visualize at once)

Comment: Any suggestions on how that would work though? I typically see lots of users connect and read in a table outside of the `ui` and `server` parts, then any filters made in the UI when the app is running gets reflected in `dplyr` chaining

Comment: It is sometimes better to preload data, or easier if the volume is not to big. But when possible, apply filter directly to your database from a reactive. Have a look at [pool](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pool/readme/README.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do much programming-wise to speed up loading data from SQL. A couple of suggestions:

- If your SQL server is remote, check the speed of your connection,
- Optimize the table in the SQL server (run `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, create histograms, etc),
- Get more RAM / faster processor.

The differences between `data.frame`, `data.table` and `dplyr` play a role *after* the data is within R.